# Options in Date Prompt in Cognos Studio

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have a date column in the database.
I have got a "Date from" and "Date to" in the prompt page to filter the data.

Now, I want to give 3 options to user in the prompt page
a) Year over Year 
b) Quarter over Quarter
c) Month over Month

Say the user chooses Date-from as Nov 1st 2004 and Date-to as Nov 1st 2015 and selects "Year over Year" in  the options 
The output should be just year over year bifurcation.

Im not able to get the 3 options and connect it to the date prompt field.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use a compound filter to test both parameters:

```
(?type? = 'Year over Year' and {Date logic using date parameters for YoY})
or 
(?type? = 'Quarter over Quarter' and {Date logic using date parameters for QoQ})
or
(?type? = 'Month over Month' and {Date logic using date parameters for MoM})
```

You didn't indicate what the Year over Year etc logic should be but you should be able to adapt the pattern above.